# Making formulas bigger in R package documentation?

Tags: r, latex, roxygen2

I'm making a package in R and I want to include some formulae in the documentation. However, some formulae contain fractions within fractions, which makes certain symbols in the formula very small and almost unreadable. Here's an example:

[image: Formula]

As you can see, the expression in the denominator of the second fraction shown in the picture is very difficult to read. I'd like to make it bigger. How could I do that?

Here's the LaTeX code which was used in the roxygen comment to produce the formula:

```
\deqn{F = \frac{k(k-2)}{2(k-1)}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{\widehat{\sigma}_{\beta\gamma}}{\widehat{\sigma}_\beta \widehat{\sigma}_\gamma})^2}[\frac{\beta^2}{\widehat{\sigma}^2_\beta}-2\frac{\widehat{\sigma}_{\beta\gamma}}{\widehat{\sigma}_\beta \widehat{\sigma}_\gamma}\frac{\beta \gamma}{\widehat{\sigma}_\beta \widehat{\sigma}_\gamma}+\frac{\gamma^2}{\widehat{\sigma}^2_\gamma}]}
```

Comment: Does using `\cfrac` instead of `\frac` help? That's the advice I see over at the LaTex site (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208367/how-to-make-nested-fractions-bigger) but I'm not sure if it works with roxygen.

Comment: Alternatively, consider putting the second part of the formula in the form [`formula`]^{-1} rather than \frac{1}{`formula`}?